# kohana bootstrap base url for me

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, kohana, kohana-3.3

I developed an webapplication in Kohana 3.3 platform
all was well till i ran application on my xampp server

where my base url was

'base_url'   => '/rkstar/'

because it resided in rkstar directory  which directly in htdocs folder

problem arose when i moved to my hosting server... it is sort of beacause of confusion and my half baked knowledge...

On server the structure is like
/
-/domains
--/mydomain
---/public_html

so when i upload code directly to my public_html directory instead of another layer higher like in xampp that was rkstar directory

i tried setting base url as

'base_url'   => '/',

ErrorException [ 2 ]: mkdir(): Permission denied ~ SYSPATH/classes/Kohana/Log/File.php [ 69 ]

which i feel turns up becoz of path set

what should my base url should be...if you are not aware in kohana base url
is the url Relative url of application.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds more like an issue with incorrect permissions. See the [Kohana Installation Guide](https://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/install).

Open up the `install.php` (with browser) that came with Kohana and see what errors it reports. According to your error message you probably need to give the webserver write permissions to the log folder (`application/logs`). The base path `/` is most likely correct.

Comment: Thanks . problem was because hosting space had hit ceiling, and that was the limiting write